# theos: 'class' may not respond to 'method' [-Werror]

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia-substrate

Header:

```
@interface Prefs
    -(void)initPrefs;
@end
```

Tweak.xm:

```
#import "Main.h"

%hook Class

-(void)method_to_override {
    [self initPrefs];

    %orig;
}

%new 

-(void)initPrefs {
    //do some stuff
}

%end
```

Above is my code, i am trying to add a new method to the class but I'm always getting

```
'Class' may not respond to 'initPrefs' [-Werror]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the method `- (void)initPrefs` in `Prefs`'s interface but you try to use it while hooking into `Class`.

You should declare your method in the class that uses it :

```
@interface Class
- (void)initPrefs
@end
```

(Alternatively, you can also disable this type of error in your Makefile by adding the line `YourTweakName_CFLAGS = -Wno-error`, but I don't encourage such a thing)

Comment: So the interface should be the same as the class I am hooking to?

Comment: Yes (if `- (void)initPrefs` is supposed to be part of this class)